Sharepoint New item not displaying correct size despite custom settings on Power Apps
My Sharepoint list "new item" is not displaying the correct height and width despite me customizing it on PowerApps. Is this a bug?

Please try to reset the settings by selecting the Small size, toggling Orientation to Portrait and then back to Landscape, and finally selecting Custom to enter your desired screen size.
